# How to limit the width of a table cell in HTML when it has white-space:nowrap?

Tags: html, width, css-tables

I've got a table cell for which I'd like to have the following effects:

```
width: 100px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

In other words, the cell should always be a single line of text (its contents are guaranteed to contain plain text without HTML markup), it should be at most 100px wide, and if the text is longer, it should be clipped.

Unfortunately, when the text gets long, the cell still stretches. Tested in IE and FF, both of which are among my target browsers.

Suggestion to add a `<div>` inside the cell and set the width to that is difficult. The table is generated from a gridview control and that just adds the specified column width to the `<td>` element and inserts the text as-is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set `max-width:100px`. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/RuAVq/

```
td{
    width: 100px;
    max-width: 100px; /* add this */
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The problem is, typically, IE doesn't support this.

Another solution, which is supported by IE, is to use `float:left`. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/RuAVq/1/

```
td{
    width: 100px;
    float: left; /* add this */
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: float:left on a table cell? O_o

Comment: @Vilx-: Yes indeed. As you can see from the second example it can be done. Those are the only two options I can think of to solve your problem.

Comment: OK... I'll accept your answer. In truth, I ended up setting width to the whole table. Not exactly what was asked here, but it suited my purpose.